# My error handler works just once and I don't understand why

Tags: excel, vba, resume

I'm trying to translate some Excel file with help of named ranges. I need to know which text is not defined yet to then add it to the names data base. For that purpose I use a VLOOKUP to compare the actual value of the cell with the values in the data base. I also don't need to translate numbers, formulas or anything that is not a string.

The only way I found to manage to add the undefined names to the data base was using an error handler for when the VLOOKUP encounters an error. The problem is this error handler works only once and I don't understand why. I've read you have to use `Resume` to do it and I have used it, but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help and sorry for the grammar mistakes.

Here's my code.

```
Sub translation()
Dim cell, cell1, cell2 As Range, search_value As String, i As Integer
i = 3
For Each cell In Hoja65.Range("D3:D10") 'Range to look up for words.
        If IsEmpty(cell) = False And IsError(cell) = False And IsNumeric(cell) = False Then ' Enter code if the cell is not empty and is not an error
                ' Check if read value is equal to any exception listed in Hoja65.Range("B3:E20")
                For Each cell1 In Hoja65.Range("E3:E10")
                        ' Check if read value is a formula beginning with "=", "+" or "-" or contains an hyperlink.
                        If cell1 = cell Or InStr(1, cell.FormulaLocal, "=", vbTextCompare) = 1 Or InStr(1, cell.FormulaLocal, "+", vbTextCompare) = 1 Or InStr(1, cell.FormulaLocal, "-", vbTextCompare) = 1 Or InStr(1, cell.Value, "http", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                                GoTo continue
                        End If
                Next cell1
                ' If read value is not equal to exception
                On Error GoTo handler
                search_value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell.Value, Hoja64.Range("F9:G550"), 2, False) ' Range where the names are defined.
                cell.Value = "=" & search_value 'Change read to defined name.
        End If
continue:
Next cell
MsgBox "Execution finished"
Exit Sub ' VERY IMPORTANT: This line must ALWAYS precede any error handler in order to avoid an infinite loop.
handler: ' Executes only if VLOOKUP doesn't find a match
        With Hoja65
                For Each cell2 In .Range(.Cells(3, 3), .Cells(i, 3))
                If cell2 = cell Then
                        GoTo continue
                Else
                        .Cells(i, 2) = cell.Address ' Save address of unsaved name.
                        .Cells(i, 3) = cell.Value ' Save value of unsaved name.
                End If
                i = i + 1
                Next cell2
        End With
        Resume continue
'ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle 2")).Select
'Selection.Formula = "=title270"
End Sub
```

Comment: Why is `On Error GoTo handler` inside the For ... Next? You do not set it to anything else.

Comment: Because I need the code to enter the handler only if there is an error in the VLOOKUP line.

Comment: Then you should put `On Error GoTo 0` after `cell.Value = "=" & search_value`

Comment: @Jeeped I don't understand that. Should I remove the `On Error GoTo handler` and write `On Error GoTo 0` after the `cell.Value = "=" $ search_value`? Doesn't that mean that if an error pop ups in the line before the `On Error GoTo 0`it debbugs and does not enter the handler headline?

Comment: Actually, I cannot follow your code at all.

Comment: FYI: `cell` and `cell1` are declared as variant, not as range

Comment: @jsotola Would you mind to explain why? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            If cell2 = cell Then
                    GoTo continue
```

This is why. You don't `GoTo`-jump in/out of an error-handling subroutine; `GoTo` doesn't "reset" the error state, so you're re-entering the "happy path" with `Err.Number <> 0`, i.e. you're still in an error state.

Replace the `GoTo` with `Resume` and you should be back on track.

```
            If cell2 = cell Then
                    Resume continue
```

Comment: Also, just a note that it's best to use as [few GoTo's as possible](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/goto.png)

Comment: @BruceWayne Absolutely... except, there's no `Continue` statement in VBA, so what OP has here (skipping a loop iteration - not in the error handler I mean) is IMO *the* single warranted use-case for `GoTo` =)

Comment: I should probably also mention that jumping in/out of a `With` block is usually a very, very bad idea.

Comment: If that condition is true I need to repeat the For for the next cell. How could I do that without GoTo?

Comment: @LuisMiguel `Resume continue` will do exactly the same thing as `GoTo continue`, except you'll be resetting the error state. Alternatively you could wrap the loop body with a `If...End If` block, and avoid `GoTo` altogether by adding 1 indentation level.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I keep getting the "Resume without Error" runtime error 20.

Comment: @LuisMiguel `Resume continue` goes under the `handler:` subroutine, not in anything above it. You can't `Resume` if you're not in an error state - that's why an error-handling subroutine should only ever run in an error state. Move the `On Error GoTo handler` instruction up to the beginning of the procedure.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Sorry for the dumb question, I already understood what you mean, thanks a lot!

Comment: @LuisMiguel I strongly recommend you follow [Jeeped's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46284289/my-error-handler-works-just-once-and-i-dont-understand-why/46284573?noredirect=1#comment79532122_46284289), too